# How to connect java to Ms Access 2010?

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc

Does anyone have any ideas of how to connect Access 2010 to java jdbc. I use this method, but when I call it, it doesn't work:

```
public void loadDb(){
   try{
       Class.forName("sun.jdbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"))       
       con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Acess Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ="+ f.getPath() + "//db//JavaAccess.accd","","");
       st = con. createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
   }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();
   }catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

//con and st are already defined
```

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers.

Comment: Note that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been **removed** from Java 8 and is not supported (ref: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) and [here](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6345277)). [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) is a popular alternative (details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)).

Answer (score 8):

According to [msdn](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en) it should be `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`. So replace this line of code:

`Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");`

Answer (score 6):

Spelling error? Perhaps this line:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Acess Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ="+ f.getPath() + "//db//JavaAccess.accd","","");
```

should be

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ="+ f.getPath() + "//db//JavaAccess.accd","","");
```

Access has 2 C's

Comment: This is a better solution for 64-bit systems running Office 64-bit. You may also need the Access Database Engine to expose the 32-bit Access database via a 64-bit interface. (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Answer (score 5):

**Create connection**

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
     String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:anime"; //anime is the database
        String username = "ipieluser"; //leave blank if none
        String password = "ipielpassword"; //leave blank if none
        try {
      Class.forName(driver);
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
        try {
      return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
     } catch (SQLException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return null;
    }
```

**How to call:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
 try {
  Connection conn = getConnection();
     Statement st = conn.createStatement();
     st = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM localTable");     

  //get and displays the number of columns
     ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
  int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
     System.out.println("resultSet MetaData column Count=" + numberOfColumns);

     st.close();
     conn.close();
 } catch(Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
}
```

Comment: hi guy, I still cannot access to the getConnection() method since it says that the type is void cannot be return, and on the other hand, it doesn't recognize the method getConnection() in some other palces.

Comment: Declare it as public it will work I have edited the code too.

Answer (score 2):

Use [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC Driver :

```java
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");  // can be omitted in most cases
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://<mdb or accdb file path>",user, password);
```

e.g.:

```java
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://c:/pippo.mdb");
```

So for your example it will be

```java
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+f.getPath()+"/db/JavaAccess.accd")
```

Answer (score 0):

Rishab's reply helped me to connect to my access database.

I did following correction in the code:

Instead of

```
String url = "jdbc:odbc:anime"; //anime is the database
```

I did

```
String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=" + "d://institute//institutedata.accdb";
```

I explicitly defined driver and full database name with path and extension.

Answer (score -1):

As today only we face the same problem and found that to check the version of java if your
version of java if the version of the java is above 7 then the sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver will not be supported so just check the version of the java.