# JDBC with ms-access?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

How to connect to a Microsoft Access-based database in a Windows using JDBC code?

What syntax is to be written for Type-1 and Type-4 types of the drivers?

```
Class.forName(" ");
```

Is the above syntax different for everytype of the driver we use? How can we define and identify the type of the driver we use??

If possible then also specify for the oracle also the driver syntax to be loaded..

Comment: You need to use the JDBC-ODBC bridge See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339055/how-to-connect-java-to-ms-access-2010 for details

Comment: I tried Google, this seemed like a reasonable page, from scanning it: http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2691&lngWId=2

Comment: con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ="+ f.getPath() + "//db//JavaAccess.accd","","");                                                    In the above line for making a connection what does DBQ means and thenafter why f.getPath() + "//db//JavaAccess.accd","",""); is written.                                                                    Thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use JDBC-ODBC bridge by calling:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver")
```

Then you can use JDBC database URL in form:

```
jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\\Nwind.mdb
```

or if you configure your database in ODBC manager you can use its alias:

```
jdbc:odbc:northwind
```

Comment: Just a note that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from the Java 8 JDK and is not supported (ref: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) and [here](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6345277)). Alternatives include [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) and [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html).

Comment: `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` does not work any more with Java8

Answer (score 7):

I recommend a cross-platform Access JDBC driver called [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html).  It works great and there are lots of examples on the site (to help the original poster.)

Answer (score 1):

JDBC/ODBC driver is a platform dependent and can be used only in Windows OS. Also, there are some platform independent JDBC drivers, for example: StelsMDB JDBC driver (http://www.csv-jdbc.com/stels_mdb_jdbc.htm)

Answer (score -1):

To connect Java with MS Access, you need a JDBC driver. I still don't think Microsoft do one do they!
http://www.easysoft.com/applications/microsoft-access/jdbc-odbc.html