# How to enter MS access JDBC driver in POM?

Tags: java, maven, ms-access, jdbc

I have to connect to MS Access database for the back end transactions. So i need to add the jdbc connector for this. I am using Maven as the build tool, So so get the MS Access dependency from Maven repository what should I be entering the POM.xml?
I tried on google search but could find relevent help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863482/jdbc-with-ms-access ?

Comment: But i want to know how to add the dependency in the POM.xml

Comment: How exactly do you connect to MS Access? And which driver are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Java provides a built in type 1 JDBC driver for ODBC data sources so you shouldn't need to add a Maven dependency for this. See: [How to connect java to Ms Access 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339055/how-to-connect-java-to-ms-access-2010)

Alternatively you could use the [Jackcess library](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) by adding this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.healthmarketscience.jackcess</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackcess</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.12</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```