# Connecting to a MSAccess Database without defining a System Data Source in Mathematica

Tags: database, jdbc, wolfram-mathematica, system

I'm trying to figure out whether there is a way to connect to an MS Access Database without having to define it as a system data resource. So far I've only come across solutions that require a named connection to be set up but none that allow to access the data just via the location of the .accdb file.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339055/how-to-connect-java-to-ms-access-2010

Comment: It does support [MDB files](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/MDB.html) directly.